# How to structure the object to different format in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm new to angular. I'm trying to restructure the object which I'm getting from the API response. I need to structure the current object to desired object.

This is the Current Object

```
let temp = {
"imagesList": {
    "de": [{
       "path": "",
       "text": "desc text"
     },
     {
       "path": "",
       "text": "desc text"
     }],
     "en": [{
       "path": "",
       "text": "desc text"
     }]
   }
}
```

Below is the Desired Object which is needed from the Current Object defined above

```
let temp = [
    {
      "path": "",
      "description": [
        {
          "language": "en",
          "text": "desc text"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "",
      "description": [
        {
          "language": "de",
          "text": "desc text"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "",
      "description": [
        {
          "language": "de",
          "text": "desc text"
        }
      ]
    }, 
 
  ]
```

How to achieve this using typescript in angular.
Sand box [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-sea-rpunc5?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: do you want it hardcoded (there will always be ONLY `de` and  `en`) or dynamic (with more languages in the furure?)

Answer (score 0):

here you have the solution:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.temp);
    const transformed: any[] =[]; 

    for (const key in this.temp.imagesList) {
      if (this.temp.imagesList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          for(const o of this.temp.imagesList[key]){
            transformed.push({
              path:o.path,
              description:[{
                language:key,
                text:o.text
              }]
            });
          }
      }
    }
    console.log(transformed);
  }
```

BTW: you would do it exactly the same with javascript. It's not really an angular or typescript question;